# Errors while installing matplotlib using pip install

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pip

I updated my `Python3` to `Python 3.10`. It still is showing `Python 3.8` as my current version. but that's not the issue. My issue is that when I went to install the `matplotlib` package using `pip install matplotlib`, I got some errors. I also tried running `pip3 install matplotlib`. I got the following errors:

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x1057db7c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
> 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known')':
> /simple/matplotlib/
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> matplotlib (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found
> for matplotlib

The I tried running `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` and got the following error:

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not
> writeable.
>
> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
> (20.2.3)

I don't get it. It wanted me to upgrade pip and then says it's already up to date?

I just need the matplotlib module installed for my Python scripts.

Comment: I don't see anything in the first error message about needing to update pip. Since you installed Python 3.10 and may even have other versions of Python before 3.8, you should run `which python` and `which pip` (as well as the 3 versions of those) to see which version you are actually running.

Comment: SO I ran pip --version and got this: pip 20.2.3

Comment: Ran python3 -V and got: Python 3.10.1

Comment: pip3 version is pip 21.2.4 and python version is Python 2.7.18

Comment: You mention in your post that it is showing 3.8 as your current version. Where is that occurring? It seems like you have upgraded to 3.10, but its in a different directory than you are expecting (not in XCode). `which python3` should return the actual address that is being used when you call python3. Have you tried `python3 -m pip install matplotlib`?

Comment: Strongly suggest you _not_ use whatever python is installed on the system, but rather use anaconda and follow the instructions for adding anaconda to your path.

Comment: Okay, so I ended up running 'python3 -m pip install matplotlib' and that did the trick. I can't say that it won't cause problems at the system level because I don't know enough to say, but I guess I will find out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install matplotlib in your organisation laptop then your organsiation could be blocking the network to connect and download the package. This is one reason its showing retrying error message. You can try disconnecting vpn if you are connecting with any and retry installing it. This error is due to network issue only.